# ResolvedParameter in Unity. Can somebody explain to when to use it?

Tags: unity-container

I am sort of new to Unity all seems to be fine but I am kind of lost when to use 
ResolvedParameter in Unity.

Googled and looked on MSDN but still cannot understand when to use it.

Do you have a simple example that could illustrate it's use.

Thanks a  lot for your help

Answer (score 10):

You may wish to configure a Type with constructor parameters of a resolved service and a string. In this case you would use ResolvedParameter.

```
Container.RegisterType<IRepository, Repository>(
            new InjectionConstructor(
                    new ResolvedParameter<IClassifier>(), 
                        "ConnectionString"));
```

Answer (score 1):

It's for method injection; see [Entering Configuration Information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc440941.aspx) on MSDN. Scroll down to "Dynamically Configuring Constructor, Property, and Method Injection" and note that the ResolvedParameter is actually a parameter to the InjectionMethod constructor.

I've never encountered a need to use it. Constructor injection will solve 95% of your issues, and property injection will solve the other 5%. (Caveat: I've only used Unity on a couple of projects, so I don't claim to be an expert.)

Answer (score 0):

As I see it its to be used when you have a constructor where at least one parameter can not be obtained from the container while the rest can. In such a situation you declare how to resolve each ctor parameter when actually creating a new instance of that type.

```
Container.RegisterSingleton<IConnectionManager, ConnectionManager>(new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter<INetworkClientFactory>(), Container.Resolve<IBackoffAlgorithm>(), 10));
```

In my example, the IConnectionManager instance obtains the first parameter from the container (via **ResolvedParameter**), the 2nd one via **Container.Resolve<>**, and the 3rd one is a hard-coded integer.

ResolvedParameter should behave equal to a direct Container.Resolve<> but looks a tad cleaner.